# FFMpeg - How to resize and change colorspace in one command

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to resize a 1080p mkv file to 1440p.  The recording is in rec601 and the scale filter will change it to rec709 for some reason.  I need to keep the recording in rec601 as the color will shift.  I cannot seem to get both -vf scale and -colorspace commands to work at the same time.  I know they can and my syntax is just wrong.  I am trying a line like ---

ffmpeg -i input.mkv -colorspace smpte170m -vf scale 2560:1440 output.mp4

I am also trying to change some of the encoding settings as well and don't know how to do that either.

Thanks for any help you could offer.

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the colorshift but this might help:

Try set the colorspace at input level

```
ffmpeg -colorspace smpte170m -i input.mkv -vf scale=2560:1440 output.mp4
```

If this does not work you could try to add a colorspace conversion filter

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "scale=2560:1440,colormatrix=bt709:smpte170m" output.mp4
```

It could also be your player that is displaying the converted video wrong. try tagging it as *rec601*

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -color_primaries smpte170m -color_trc smpte170m -colorspace smpte170m -vf scale=2560:1440 output.mp4
```